# Hide a row in table with specific number of characters

Tags: javascript

I need to hide the flight row with the flight number longer than 6 characters (including the `EY-`) for example when the page loads the row for the `EY-5306`should be hidden completely and only show the row with the flight number `EY-513`.

```
<tr>
   <td>EY-5306</td>
   <td>29 Oct 2019</td>
   <td>07:00 am</td>
   <td>AUH</td>
   <td>AMM</td>
   <td>
      <a href="https://www.example.com?flightNumber=5306" role="link">Check flight status <img src="/images/test0.jpg" alt="image" class="check-flight-arrow"></a>
   </td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td>EY-513</td>
   <td>29 Oct 2019</td>
   <td>10:35 am</td>
   <td>AUH</td>
   <td>AMM</td>
   <td>
      <a href="https://www.example.com?flightNumber=513" role="link">Check flight status <img src="/images/test1.jpg" alt="image" class="check-flight-arrow"></a>
   </td>
</tr>
```

When the JS script runs I want to see the table but that exclude the row with the flight number `EY-5306` because the number of characters are more than 6.

Comment: use the `string.length` and make a condition. For example: `if( word.length == 6){ display ;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `.text().length;` to get characters count.

```js
$('tr td:nth-child(1)').each(function(){
  var value = $(this).text().length;
  if (value > 6){
  $(this).parent().hide();
  }
});
```

```css
table{
width:100%;
border:1px solid #ddd;
}

td{
border:1px solid #ddd;
padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><td>EY-5306</td><td>29 Oct 2019</td><td>07:00 am</td><td>AUH</td><td>AMM</td><td><a href="https://www.example.com?flightNumber=5306" role="link">Check flight status
<img src="/images/test0.jpg" alt="image" class="check-flight-arrow"></a></td></tr>

<tr><td>EY-513</td><td>29 Oct 2019</td><td>10:35 am</td><td>AUH</td><td>AMM</td><td><a href="https://www.example.com?flightNumber=513" role="link">Check flight status
<img src="/images/test1.jpg" alt="image" class="check-flight-arrow"></a></td></tr>
</tbody>
<table>
```

Comment: Hi Ahmed this works for me when I am placing the following code in the browser but since I am injecting the code from an application as a layer the same is not working for a reason.
<br><br>
I am sharing the link with you for the page. https://www.etihad.com/en/manage/flight-tracker
<br><br>
Change the option to "Origin and destination" search for Abu Dhabi to Amman and click Find. you will see the table I was talking about above.
<br><br>
$('tr td:nth-child(1)').each(function(){
  var value = $(this).text().length;
  if (value > 6){
  $(this).parent().hide();
  }
});

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly ? it works on console.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it for me. I am using an A/B test platform called adobe target. It injects your code at the very beginning of the page load but actually the code needs to run after user does the search by filling the form and clicking the Find button. The table loads after that.

Comment: Try this `$(".fs-ond-submit-btn button").click(function(){  setTimeout(function(){ XXXX }, 10);   })` and replace `XXXX` with previous code.